# System resets from code only with active breakpoint

Tags: arm, stm32, breakpoints, stm32cubeide, nucleo

Dear people of stackoverflow,

Beginner here.

I wrote a small piece of code which should reset my MCU (STM32G071RBT6) when a button is pressed and a certain condition is met (see code below).
The button is active low, and an internal pull-up resistor is set active.

The code is set up using STM32CubeIde, using the integrated CubeMX to set up a basic structure and configuration.

```
// The problematic stuff:
if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BT1_GPIO_Port, BT1_Pin) == 0) {
    if (latch == 1) {
        latch = 0;
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD4_GPIO_Port, LD4_Pin, 0);
    } else if (latch == 0) {
        __DSB();            // Wait for flash writes to complete!
        __disable_irq();    // Disable ALL interrupts (because of a running timer).
        NVIC_SystemReset(); // Go for reset!

        // NVIC_SystemReset(); can be replaced with:
        //SCB->AIRCR = 0x05FA0004;// Write the system reset key and bit.
        
        while(1);       // Wait for the hardware to do it's thing...
    }
    HAL_Delay(500); // Very crude debounce, for now.

}
```

When I run this, compiled either as debug or as release, the first button press works. I.e. the latch is set to 0 and the output is set low. Then on the second button press the MCU never resets, unless I set a breakpoint anywhere in my program.

To summarize my problem:
The curious thing is this code works perfect, IF a breakpoint is set anywhere in my code (also outside of this specific routine). When, however, there isn't any breakpoint set the MCU does not reset. This I do not understand.

This code is currently running on a NUCLEO-G071RB, on which I've tested all sorts of things before without a problem.

I've tried several things:

1. Set breakpoints to see if the code is actually running properly (the rest at least) and to see how far I can get to the system reset.
2. Read the registers of the GPIO input to see if there really is a signal present. There is.
3. Try different build settings, i.e. debug and release, this makes no difference.

EDIT:
A very curious thing happend:
I rewrote the code, and it works!

```
// The problematic stuff:
if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BT1_GPIO_Port, BT1_Pin) == 0 && latch ==1) {
    latch = 0;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD4_GPIO_Port, LD4_Pin, 1);
    HAL_Delay(500);             // Very crude debounce, for now.
}
if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BT1_GPIO_Port, BT1_Pin) == 0 && latch == 0) {
    __DSB();                        // Wait for flash writes to complete!
    __disable_irq();                // Disable ALL interrupts.
    NVIC_SystemReset(); // Go for reset!
    while(1);                       // Wait for the hardware to do it's thing...
    HAL_Delay(500);             // Very crude debounce, for now.
}
```

I shall read up on the actual functionality of the `else if ()` statement. Possibly my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Was your first code included in some kind of infinite loop? I've assumed it must be, but if it wasn't, then clearly it wouldn't work. Maybe you should post more of your code.

Comment: Hi pmacfarlane,

Both the first and second iteration of this code snippet are in the main() function.

Comment: Well OK, but what else is in `main()`? What comes after the first code snippet? Is the first snippet the body of a loop?